# How does Akka handle message versions?

Tags: java, serialization, ipc, akka, actor

How does [Akka](http://akka.io/) handle the serialization of different versions of messages of the same type, but different versions?  For example, can an Actor X that expects version 1 of message A receive and process version 2 of message A from Actor Y that has an extra field?  How does it handle the case where version 3 of message A might have removed or renamed a field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the serializer used. Akka has configurable serialization, so you have many options (see docs: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/serialization.html).

In general, it is recommended to use a serializer that enables you to design for backward and forward compatibility, for example Protobuf.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I didn't know that Akka supports different serialization options, including Google Protocol Buffers.

Comment: Akka has _pluggable_ serialization, so you are free to handle it in any way you can imagine :-)